# Count the rows in one range based on both a key and the existence of a value in another range

Tags: google-sheets

This is likely a duplicate, but it's difficult to search for or to recognize when I have found it.

In Google Sheets, I want a formula for E1:E4 (pink) that will give me the count of rows in A1:B5 (blue) where the key ("Aaron") matches the the value in D and the value ("9/4/2023") exists in A7:A8 (yellow).

The result is the numbers shown, which I entered manually. I am looking for the **simplest** or most common approach. Thank you for any guidance!

[image: A table matching the description in the question body]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter()` and `match()`, like this:

```
=counta(ifna(filter(A$1:A$5, A$1:A$5 = D1, match(B$1:B$5, A$7:A$8,0))))
```

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197) and [match()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378).

Comment: Wonderful, and so obvious upon deconstruction. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You look at this formula:

```
=MAP(G2:G5,LAMBDA(x,IFERROR(QUERY(A1:B5,"Select Count(B) Where B >= Date '"&TEXT(A7,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"' And B <= Date '"&TEXT(A8,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"' AND A Like '"&x&"' Group by A Label Count(B)'' "),0)))
```

or

```
=QUERY(A1:B5,"Select A, Count(B) Where B >= Date '"&TEXT(A7,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"' And B <= Date '"&TEXT(A8,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"' Group by A LAbel Count(B)'' ")
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U_zQAq-_LP00NGksEaQSoUIWUbcrTHqDmPq_hrZ2C0Y/edit?usp=sharing